# specialize a pool class based on whether create function is passed in

Tags: c++

I have a templated pool class that manages of lifetime of a bunch of objects. Normally, it will call new and delete as needed, but I can also pass in a create function and destroy function.

Now, for some users of this class I'd like to have a private constructor and only allow passing in a create / destroy function. This causes a compilation error because the "new T" line is still in the pool class even though it's not used. So far, I've solved this by making pool a friend of the class in question. This still leaves open the possibility for misuse (eg by creating a pool of the particular object by hand and not passing create / destroy functions in), so I'm wondering what's the best way to specialize the pool class so I can have true private constructors on its template arguments without using friend.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your intent correctly, I think I'd do something like this:

```
template <class T>
struct constructor { 
    T *make() { return new T; }
    void destroy(T const *t) { delete t; }
};

template <class T, class ctor = constructor<T> >
class Pool {
    ctor c; 
    // ...
    T *t = c.make():

    // ...

    c.destroy(t);
};
```

If the user passes a constructor object, your code uses its make/destroy functions. If they don't pass one, then the `constructor` template will be used, which will use `new` and `delete`.

As a minor variation, you may prefer to have the `make` and `destroy` as `static` member functions, so inside of `Pool`, you'd just use `ctor::make();` and `ctor::destroy(t);`.

Answer (score 0):

You could specialize your template as needed:

```
template <typename T, bool Constructible>
struct Pool
{
    T * make()
    {
        return maker(std::common_type<Constructible>());
    }

    T * maker(std::common_type<false>) { return T::create(); }

    T * maker(std::common_type<true>)  { return new T(); }
};

Pool<Foo, true> fooPool;    // uses "new Foo();"
Pool<Bar, false> barPool;   // uses "Bar::create();"
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the most flexible solution. This is based on traits - like other answer, but   it is extremely easy to use. Just put your specialized functions if you need to change construction or destruction.

My proposal:

```
template <typename T>
T* std_new() { return new T(); }
template <typename T>
void std_delete(T* p) { delete p; }

template <typename T, T*(*Create_)() = std_new<T>, void(*Destroy_)(T*) = std_delete<T> >
class Pool {
public:
   T* create() { return Create_(); }
   void destroy(T* p) { Destroy_(p); }
};
```

And its usage:

```
Pool<int> pi;
int* new_int_7() { return new int(7); }
Pool<int, new_int_7> pi7;
```

Want to keep arrays in your pool:

```
template <typename T, int N>
T* std_new_arr() { return new T[N](); }
template <typename T>
void std_delete_arr(T* p) { delete [] p; }

Pool<int, std_new_arr<int, 6>, std_delete_arr<int> > piarr;
```

---

However consider if using some standard container with specialized allocator (if needed) could be the best choice.